# VIM syntax color a word containing a word or ending with a word

Tags: vim, syntax, colors, match, highlight

How can I color a matching word (only this word in a line) in vim containing a substring?

For example the given line:

```
myStruct__st name;
```

I would like to color the whole word:

```
myStruct__st
```

which is containing the substring `__st`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want specifically your highlight to *end* with `__st` rather than just contain it somewhere, and presumably begin with some other characters, maybe something like this:

```
highlight MyHighlightGroup ctermbg=blue guibg=blue "or whatever color
match MyHighlightGroup /\<\S\+__st\>/
```

Breaking it down, you've got `\<` for the start of a word, `\S\+` for one or more non-whitespace characters, `__st` for your identifier substring, and then `\>` for the end of the word.